# Adding a lwc component to standard New record popup

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a custom lightning component which I need to include when creating new records.

What I need to do is add this custom lwc component to the standard New popup, which shows when clicking the New button. Need to know whether this is currently possible, or whether it will require creating a custom New page.

[image: example popup]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to replace the whole "new record page" with a custom component. You can not just replace the small portion of it.

You can replace the whole "new popup", but not directly with LWC, you need to wrap your Lwc component into Aura Component.

Create an aura component, and implement these interfaces in it.

```
lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName
```

Sample code.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">
   <c:myLwc/>
</aura:component>
```

Then you can override the standard action using this aura component. [See docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_action_overrides.htm)

Also, make sure that you lwc has the @api attribute named `recordId` in it.

Comment: Thank for that. However I don't want to replace the whole popup. I only want to add the custom component as a field to the existing popup

Comment: That is not possible, I have updated my answer @MichaelDann

Comment: Ok. Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: Welcome @MichaelDann